# Solving efficiently $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Calculating efficiently $$AX = C$$ 
Given $$ A = I + BB^{T} $$ where $ B $ is an orthogonal matrix of $ n \times m $.
 Since $B$ is a semi-orthogonal matrix, does $ BB^{T} = I_n $ hold?  If not, how do I compute $ A^{-1} $?

Comment: Let's use an example. Let B = 1 x 2 and $B^T$ = 2 x 1. If we multiply a $BB^T$, we get a 1x1 size matrix. If we multiply $B^TB$, we get a 2x2 matrix. The inverse of a matrix is when $BB^T = I$.  Can the inverse be solved for? $BB^T = I = B^TB$? Is that statement true? No, so the inverse can't be solved for. Therefore, $BB^T \neq BB^T$.

Comment: my question is not whether $BB^{T}$ and  $B^{T}B$ are equal or not. My question is whether  $BB^{T} = I$? If it is then finding $A^{-1}$ is quite straight forward. If it is not, then how to solve it? or we do it using [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula)

Comment: Is $m\ge n$ or $n\ge m?$

Comment: Can be assumed to be either.

Comment: If $m\ge n$ and $B$ is $n\times m$ then $BB^T=I_n.$ If $m<n$ then $BB^T\ne I_n.$

Comment: Okay, so you mean to say that if $ m \geq n $ then $ A = 2 I $? And for the other part, how do we calculate?

Comment: If $m<n$ I think that the inverse of $A$ depends on $B$. I don't know if there is an expressión for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, $\ A^{-1} = I_n - \frac{1}{2}BB^T\ $.  For $\ m \ge n\ $, as pointed out in the comments, $\ BB^T = I_n\ , A = 2I_n\ $, and the result is (almost) trivial.  On the other hand, if $\ m < n\ $  then $\ B^TB = I_m\ $, and $\ BB^TBB^T = BI_mB^T = BB^T\ $.  Thus
\begin{eqnarray}
\ A\left(I_n - \frac{1}{2}BB^T\right) &=& \left(I_n + BB^T\right)\left(I_n - \frac{1}{2}BB^T\right)\\
&=& I_n + BB^T - \frac{1}{2}BB^T - \frac{1}{2}BB^TBB^T\\
&=& I_n + BB^T - \frac{1}{2}BB^T - \frac{1}{2}BB^T \\
&=&I_n
\end{eqnarray}